# Phonegap contacts.find Success not firing on first attempt - Doubling results on the second

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm getting a weird issue in PhoneGap 3.3.0 (iOS, haven't tested on Android yet) where when I execute the contacts.find it's not firing a success or error. As soon as I fire it a second time it's working, however it is giving me each contact entry twice...

```
// Set the options for the contacts request
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter = "";
            options.multiple = true;

            filter = ["displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers", "emails", "photos"];

            // Getting the contacts
            navigator.contacts.find(filter, function(contacts){
                console.log(contacts);

                // If contacts were found:
                // For each contact result...
                contacts.forEach(function(item, index){
                    // Check to make sure they have a first or last name
                    if(item.name.givenName != null || item.name.familyName != null) {
                        // If that have a first or last name:
                        // Add the persons first and/or last name to the mycontacts array
                        mycontacts.pushObject((item.name.givenName != null ? item.name.givenName+" " : "")+(item.name.familyName != null ? item.name.familyName : ""));
                    }
                });

                console.log(mycontacts);

                // Mark "gotcontacts" as being done successfully to prevent unrequired calls
                that.set("gotcontacts", true);

                that.send('loaderOff');
            }, function(error){
                console.log("couldn't get contacts");
                // If there was an error getting the contacts
                alert("Sorry, we couldn't find any contacts.");

                that.send('loaderOff');
            }, options);
```

I'm triggering the call on a button press.

If anyone has any ideas as to why this would be that would be great. Right now I'm lost!

Comment: I am also faced almost same problem. The success event not fired from DeviceReady event only fired from button click event.
Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution at the time. I ended up using another plugin for this. Having said that though I have since found if you delete the phonegap platform having the issue then add it again it usually solves plugin related issues.